# Trying to save comport settings

Tags: c#, com, serial-port, save, settings

So I'm trying to populate a combo-box with the available com ports, on a settings page.

Once the setting as been chosen I would like that setting to be retained and be available globally with the save settings function via a save button. I think there must be an easier way than this!

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pumpPort = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(pumpPort);

    this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    switch (Properties.Settings.Default.Setting)
    {
     case "COM1":
        this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.COMPORT1;
            break;

     case "COM2":
        this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.COMPORT2;
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
```

Needless to say this does not retain any settings after `form2` is closed.  I would like it to retain even after the program has exited let alone `form2`.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the default setting and invoke save on the comboBox1 change event.

Like so:

```
private void Init()
{
      ...
      this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged +=
           new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
        System.EventArgs e)
{
      //other event code
      ...
      var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
      var port = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = port;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;`
```

You are setting the selected item of the combo box.

I think you really want to reverse that.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem
```

You would want to do the assignment in the change event of the combo box however, so that when a user selects the value, your settings are updated and saved.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pumpPort = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(pumpPort);
}
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

As @wbennett notes in his answer, make sure that the indexchanged event is set in either your codebehind, or preferably in your designer.